# h5py Import error when using bat file but not in spyder

Tags: batch-file, importerror, h5py

I'm trying to run a python script using bat file. I get the error " ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found" when importing h5py.
However, when I import it in spyder terminal, it works fine.

I'm running python from environment where h5py is installed.

bat file:

```
cd C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my_env
python "C:\Users\id\Desktop\ex.py"
pause
```

ex.py:

```
import h5py
```

I tried uninstalling and re installing h5py.
I have tried with h5py version 2.8.0, 2.9.0.
Still not able to solve the issue.

Comment: Is `h5py.dll` in directory `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\my_env` ?

Comment: You have to be careful about setting the environment. Changing directories to the `my_env` folder **does not** set the `my_env` environment. You have to run the conda command: `conda activate env_name` (eg `my_env`). You can verify by simply running `python` on the command line then enter `import h5py` on the first line.

Comment: @kcw78 Thank you. Activating the environment in bat file solved the issue.